# Model attributes are magically being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have code that lets me automatically create a record or update a record's attributes if it exists already.

The code looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.update_or_create(attributes)
    user = first || new
    user.assign_attributes(attributes)
    user.save
    user
  end
end
```

And when I call it, I'm able to do this:

`User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).update_or_create(display_name: hash.display_name)`

Executing that code would either find a record with a matching `provider` and `uid`and update it's `display_name` OR create an entirely new record with all 4 previously mentioned attributes set.

How does this work?

Specifically, I can't seem to understand how the call to `user.save` is able to "obtain" the attributes for `provider` and `uid` as they were only provided in the search context and NOT passed in as attributes to `update_or_create`.

Answer (score 0):

#### `User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth`

above you have a User::ActiveRecord_Relation this a collection of class users

#### `def self.update_or_create`

self.update_or_create this method is a class method of user

#### `user = first || new`

now you have instance a first of collection or initialize a new instance of class User

#### `user.assign_attributes(attributes)`

here you are assigning attributes for the new instance or first instance of collection

```
def self.update_or_create(attributes)
  puts "here I have a = #{self.class.name}" #user class
  user = first || new
  puts "here I have a = #{user.class.name}" #instance
  user.assign_attributes(attributes)
  user.save
  user
end
```

---

### #edit

for you fully understand please install the `gem 'pry'` in your `GemFile`

this gem will able to debug your code when it's running

```
def self.update_or_create(attributes)
  binding.pry ## add this your code and run this method in your app or rails console
  # at this moment when you execute the code the pry will provide a prompt
  # and type a self and press enter
  # and type a user and press enter
  # and type a next and press enter
  # you will see step by step want is happens 
  user = first || new
  user.assign_attributes(attributes)
  user.save
  user
end
```

for more info please watch this [RailsCast Pry With Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thank you for answering but i don't understand. I can't follow your answer and i also don't understand how the params passed to `where` make their way into the instance

Comment: Let me know if a need a more help to understand that